# Subset quarterly data with yyyyQQ factor time variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I'm trying to subset Eurostat data with a greater than sign on a quarterly time variable:

```
install.packages("SmarterPoland")
library(SmarterPoland)

GDP <- getEurostatRCV(kod = "namq_gdp_c")
```

(big dataset)

now the problem:

```
GDP <- subset(GDP, (time > "1989Q4"))
```

which works perfectly for yearly data (time > "1989") but for quarterly data I'm guessing that R doesn't understand that 'time' is a ascending variable. I get this error:

> Warning message:
>
> In Ops.factor(time, "1989Q4") : > not meaningful for factors

Any help would be very nice :-)

edit: can someone who is allowed to create a tag "quarterly" or "quarterlydata"? might help google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yearqtr` class in the `zoo` package:

```
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)
> as.yearqtr("1989Q3") < as.yearqtr("1989Q4")
[1] TRUE
```

To convert the column:

```
GDP$time = as.yearqtr(GDP$time)
```

I don't think it's necessary to create a tag for quarterly data since it fits in the "time-series" category, but I did add that tag to your post.

Comment: Thanks so much! After using that subset works perfectly!